# Determining which linear function is largest

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, algorithms

I have a collection of linear functions of form $y_i= m_ix + b_i$ for positive integers $m,b,x$. I am trying to efficiently determine which equation (i.e. which $i$) corresponds to the largest $y_i$ given some $x$, for many $x$ (it is easy enough to do this for a single $x$, just update the equations and sort, but this is over many $x$ so this is no longer appropriate).

For example if $y_1 = 3x + 7$ and $y_2 = 5x + 4$, if $x=1$, then $y_1 = 10$ and $y_2 = 9$, so $i=1$ is maximal.

But when $x=2$, then $y_1 = 13$ and $y_2 = 14$, so now $i=2$ is maximal.

One important thing I can note is that once one equation meets/surpasses another, it will always be larger.

I would ask this on StackOverflow but since it's math related they'd just tell me to come post it here anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of the line $y_1$ with the largest $b$ value. Say it has slope $m_1$. Then consider other lines with larger slopes. Calculate their intersections with line $y_1$.

Find the line whose intersection with $y_1$ corresponds to the lowest $x$-value. Call this line $y_2$. Instead of keeping track of $y_1$, keep track of $y_2$ and do the same thing as above. Find all lines with larger slopes, calculate their intersection points, etc.

Keep doing this until you've exhausted your collection of lines.

You should then have a list of the largest lines for each value of $x$. Originally, the line with the highest $y$-intercept was chosen, but as other lines overtook it we had new lines. If we were to graph the segments of the line we kept track of it would look somewhat like a jagged parabola.

For a given $x$ you just find the line which was maximal at the given time.

Comment: I think so. Were you looking for a solution in faster time?

I think that the first calculation is $O(n^2)$ but once the lines are generated and the list is made we can keep that list and run for each $x$ in $O(n)$.

Comment: @Mart: I think you can get $O(n\log n)$ by splitting the lines arbitrarily into two groups, computing the max function of each group recursively, and then merging the two lists.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: See my answer for a hint on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify whether the lines are given **before** all the queries, which would be much easier than if you can intersperse insertions and deletions of the lines among the queries. In both cases, what you would need is the convex region bounded below by all the lines. If all the lines are given in advance, it should not be hard to figure out how to obtain the region in $O(n\cdot\log(n))$ time for $n$ lines. However, if you have a dynamically changing set of lines, it would be much harder.

To get the $O(n\cdot\log(n))$ time complexity as claimed, sort by gradient and do a single pass using a stack, which takes amortized constant time per line because once a line is popped off the stack it is never pushed back on.

Comment: Sorry yes, the lines are before the queries

Comment: Sorting by slope is such an obvious idea once you hear it, +1.

Comment: I actually tried this approach already (sorting by slope) as a side experiment and using a stack but the results never seemed to fully match my brute force method. I may have implemented it wrong though. What is the "convex region" and how does this matter? This is over several possible $x$, not just one.

Comment: @Mart: It can be tricky to get such stack-based solutions completely right if you are not careful. Try to prove it correct and you should be able to find any flaws. At each step the next line is steeper than all the previous ones and so must intersect the current region boundary somewhere. We find it by looking at the most steep part of the boundary first. If it does not intersect that part it must intersect an earlier part so we pop the steepest segment off. Repeat until it intersects the steepest part.

Comment: @Mart: I've already fully specified the convex region in my answer; the region bounded below by all the lines.

Comment: @Mart: You build the region first and worry about queries later. After you have built the region you can answer every query in $\log(n)$ time by a binary search to determine which part of the region boundary is relevant.

Comment: I am not sure how you can "bound" a line, since a line by definition is an "infinitely progressing" thing, unless you mean taking the max query and then "capping" everything off within a bounding region first?

Comment: @mart: "is bounded below by X" is a standard English phrase that means "has X as a lower bound" that implies in this case that the lines are below the region.